# How to create function to execute another function several times each after 1 sec

Tags: javascript

I created Function name `myfunction()`, I need to create another function let's call it `repeateMyFunction()`, I need it to repeat the function job several time after 1 second + I need it make the function appear in many lines  not only 1 line using for loop or something , please help me without creating new code i need this edit in my code  + "i need only JS codes " (it was a python app and i turn it from scratch to this )

1 = tried to simple put the function call into myfunction() 
2 = try to make for loop to do that work and repeat the function but i couldn't

result i need to be like this :

```
Ahmed will playing playstation: typeof is string
(1sec)
Ahmed was playing games: typeof is string
(1sec)
Ahmed is playing football: typeof is string
```

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    function myFunction() {
      var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 0);
      var templates = ["{{noun}} is   {{verb}} football", "{{noun}}  was  {{verb}}   games", "{{noun}} will {{verb}} playstation"];

      var str = "{{noun}} is {{verb}} football";
      var n = str.search("{{noun}}");
      var y = str.search("{{verb}}");
      var res = str.split(" ");
      var list = [];

      var str = templates[random];
      var myis = str.slice(8, 13);
      if (n != -1) {
        list.push("Ahmed");

        list.push(myis);
      }
      if (y != -1) {
        list.push("playing");
      }
      var res = str.slice(22, 34);
      var tryit = list.join(" ") + res;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tryit + ": typeof     is " +
        typeof(tryit);
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: why cannot use `setTimeout`?

Comment: You can learn more about [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
//@param interval:Number -- The unit of `interval` is milliseconds
function repeateMyFunction (func, interval) {
  var taskID = setInterval(func, interval);
  return taskID;
}

// Use repeateMyFunction
// It will call `myFunction` once per second
var taskID = repeateMyFunction(myFunction, 1000);

// stop calling loop
clearInterval(taskID);
```

Comment: it works, but clearInterval(taskId) didn't  i made it like this

Comment: <button onclick="clearInterval(id)">stopIT</button>

Comment: <button onclick="repeateMyFunction(myFunction, 1000)"> this works but can't clearInterval

Comment: can some one rewrite the code with setinterval and clear interval  with buttons and event trigger to it using onclick

Comment: If you need to use the button control function call, please make taskID a global variable, such as: <button onclick="window.taskID = repeateMyFunction(myFunction, 1000);">Start</button>  <button onclick="clearInterval(window.taskID);">Stop</button>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` function to call a function repeatedly and to stop it add  your `setInterval` in to a variable and then use `clearInterval` with variable name.

Add this code in your script `setInterval(repeateMyFunction, 1000);`

It will call `repeateMyFunction` function every 1 second.

Comment: the clearInterval didn't work but the set work , i think the problem in pramertes i added was like this <button onclick="setInterval(myFunction, 1000)></button> <button onclick="clearInterval(taskID)"></button